# Automate width size of UICollectionViewCell - Swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

How can I a `UICollectionViewCell` with automate `width` size base size `string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this to calculate the width from a string

```
let padding = 30

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let lbl = UILabel() 
    lbl.text = arr[indexPath.item] // arr = [String]()
    let si = lbl.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width:CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height:40)) 
    print(si.width)
    return CGSize(width:si.width + padding , height:40)
}
```

---

```
class VCName:UIViewController , UICollectionViewDelegate  , UICollectionViewDataSource , UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout { }
```

Comment: @ Sh_Khan. How to use sizeForItemAt?

Comment: @ Sh_Khan. Thank's a lot. ;-)